# Chain of packets in MathLink: are the packets always strictly ordered?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathlink

The Documentation does not state clear the order of packets returned
by slave kernel via `MathLink`. It is natural to suppose that (when
sending an input expression with head `EnterExpressionPacket` and working in standard mode):

1) the last packet before the next `InputNamePacket` is always
`ReturnExpressionPacket`

2) there may be always only one `ReturnExpressionPacket` and one
`OutputNamePacket` for one `EnterExpressionPacket`

3) `ReturnExpressionPacket` is always the next after `OutputNamePacket`

4) after `MessagePacket` the next packet is always `TextPacket` with
all contents of that message

5) there are only 7 types of returned packets in the standard mode: `InputNamePacket`, `OutputNamePacket`, `ReturnExpressionPacket`, `DisplayPacket`, `DisplayEndPacket`, 
`MessagePacket`, `TextPacket`.

Which of these statements are true?

Comment: Perhaps it would be useful to note that John Fultz has already given a detailed [`answer`](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/browse_thread/thread/d9fd3f080fa58dd7) to this question on the official newsgroup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- 1 is probably not guaranteed.
- 2 is definitely not true (evaluate: "2+2\n2+3").
- 3 is probably true but probably not guaranteed.
- I believe 4 is true.
- 5 is not guaranteed.

In general you should write your code to not rely on the order of packets coming from the kernel.  The evaluation should be considered "active" until you receive a new InputNamePacket.  OutputNamePacket should update some variable.  ReturnExpressionPacket should use the current output name from that variable.  If you receive an unknown packet simply ignore it and move on to the next packet.

Comment: Example where 1 is not true: "foo = 1;" will not produce a ReturnExpressionPacket. The kernel just returns an InputNamePacket.